# pyspark export parquet not in snappy compression

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Reading documentation for [spark.write.parquet](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet.html) does not show me options to change compression for the exported parquet. To go around the default exported parquet format I am able to convert pyspark dataframe into a pandas dataframe and export to parquet from that.

This work but is highly inefficient are there option to change exported parquet compression (default is snappy) without having to convert dataframe to pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

You can change it in spark conf

```
spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec
```

Or you can pass this option to writer like this:

```
df.write.option("compression","gzip").parquet(filename)
```

List of possible formats for Spark 3.3:

> This can be one of the known case-insensitive shorten names (none,
> uncompressed, snappy, gzip, lzo, brotli, lz4, and zstd)

You can check docu for more details [Docu](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html)

Comment: Thanks, that does change compression engine! I thought it will also change the structure of the result parquet but it is still partitioned. Do you know if I can export parquet from pyspark as a single file instead of a parquet folder ?

Comment: If you want to have all of your data in one file you can use coalesce(1) before write. This function call will move all of your data to one partition which will be later saved to one file on the output. Remember that in this case write will not be done in parallel so you are loosing Spark advantages here

Comment: Yes, I get that but for export need this works, thanks!